# Next item displayed from array instead of the expected value

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

This is a very basic java question, I have an array of strings

```
String[] navTitles = new String[] {Home, HR, company, joiner, next};
```

These titles are shown in a ListView. When the first item is clicked, I have to display a certain list, else if any other title is clicked I have to show a different list. The first (default) list should be the one which appears on clicking the first item. The issue is,if I click on a title, the list related to the next title is displayed. When I click the last title i get an error:-

```
    05-02 04:47:38.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1490): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
05-02 04:47:38.787: E/AndroidRuntime(1490):     at com.abc.attini.Home.displayView(Home.java:600)
```

Here is my code:--

```
for (int j = 0; j < navMenuTitles.length && j < iconColors.length; j++) {
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[j], iconColors[j]));

}
adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), navDrawerItems);
mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());




private class SlideMenuClickListener implements 
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {

}
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
                            int position,  long id) {

        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}


private void displayView(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (position == 0) {
        fragment = new HomeFragment(SPHostUrl, encodedAccountName, 
                deviceAuthKey, usersname, avatarUrl, fullName, 
                getApplicationContext(), myFinalNewsList);

    } else {
        String myPosition = null;

        myPosition = navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle(); //Line 600


        companyNewsList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(myFinalNewsList, 
                new ArticleFilter(myPosition)));

        fragment = new HomeFragment(SPHostUrl, encodedAccountName, deviceAuthKey, 
                usersname, avatarUrl, fullName, getApplicationContext(), companyNewsList);

    }
```

Comment: which line is the 600th line of `Home.java` class?

Comment: @Hamid please check the updates

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct value of position to the function ?

Comment: @Swayam When I click the second title I get the position =2, whereas I should get position =1

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what I am asking is are you passing the correct value to the function? Can you Log the value before sending ?

Comment: @Swayam I have added some more code to the question. can you check now?

Comment: Post the code where you have initialized the `navDrawerItems`.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

Error occur because index value reach more than the index.

```
private void displayView(int position) 
{
    Fragment fragment = null;
    position = position % length; //length of your array 

    if(position==0)
    {
        fragment = new HomeFragment(SPHostUrl,encodedAccountName,deviceAuthKey,usersname,avatarUrl, fullName,getApplicationContext(),myFinalNewsList);
    }
    else
    {
        String myPosition = null;

        myPosition =  navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle(); //Line 600


        companyNewsList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(myFinalNewsList, new ArticleFilter(myPosition)));
         fragment = new HomeFragment(SPHostUrl,encodedAccountName,deviceAuthKey,usersname,avatarUrl, fullName,getApplicationContext(),companyNewsList);

    }
}
```

above code works fine at my end because it makes position under array length .

Comment: @user3534519 whats is your length ?

Comment: the length of the array is 5

Comment: Have u check this code on java file because run smoothly at my end